# Determining $L$ from $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{3}{L}$, $\sin(\beta)=\frac{2}{L}$, $\alpha + \beta = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> I have a trigonemtric problem that boils down to solving the following system of equations for $L$:
>
> $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{3}{L}$$
> $$\sin(\beta)=\frac{2}{L}$$
> $$\alpha + \beta = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

My first thought was to solve the system using the identity $$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin\alpha \times \cos\beta + \cos\alpha \times \sin\beta$$ This gives me a single equation in terms of $L$, but it's messy. Is there an easier way to solve for $L$?

Comment: Well you could use that $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{3}{2}\sin(\beta)$. Then $\sin^2(\alpha)=\frac{9}{5}\sin^2(\beta)\to 1-\cos^2(\alpha)=\frac{9}{4}-\frac{9}{4}\cos^2(\beta)$, and simplify. After plugging in it shouldn't be too messy.

Comment: It would be a little easier to go with the cosine formula:
$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
so that
$$\left(\;\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\sin\alpha\sin\beta\;\right)^2=\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta = ( 1-\sin^2\alpha)(1-\sin^2\beta)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

From
$$\alpha=\dfrac\pi3-\beta$$ we draw

$$\sin\alpha=\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos\beta-\frac12\sin\beta,$$
and
$$\left(\sin\alpha+\frac12\sin\beta\right)^2=\frac34(1-\sin^2\beta).$$

This is an easy quadratic equation in $L$.